# Getting invalidBSON MongoDb $project with Python

Tags: python, mongodb

When I run the query bellow on terminal it works, but when I use it on Jupter Notebook it doens't. I get an invalidBSON error:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb...")
mydb = myclient["myDataBase"]
mycol = mydb["myCollection"]

x = pd.DataFrame(mycol.find({}, {"custom_field": {"$elemMatch": {"app_custom_field_id": 1871}}}))
```

error = InvalidBSON

I've tried different query aproachs to get a similar results, all of then works on the terminal:

```
{"custom_field.app_custom_field_id": 1871}, {"_id": 0, "custom_field.app_custom_field_id.$": 1}
```

or

```
{"custom_field.app_custom_field_id": 1871},{"_id": 0, "custom_field": {$elemMatch: {"app_custom_field_id": 1871}}}
```

When I use a simple query without the projection part, it works, but I need to limit the data.

I appreciate any help.

The full tracetrack of the error:

```
InvalidBSON                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-4c5a5acd8749> in <module>
----> 1 x = pd.DataFrame(mycol.find({}, {"custom_field": {"$elemMatch": {"app_custom_field_id": 1871}}}))
      2 
      3 #x.to_csv(r'C:/Users/Documents/Inngage/Tabelas/output.csv', index = False, header=True)
      4 
      5 for doc in x:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    500         elif isinstance(data, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(data, (str, bytes)):
    501             if not isinstance(data, (abc.Sequence, ExtensionArray)):
--> 502                 data = list(data)
    503             if len(data) > 0:
    504                 if is_dataclass(data[0]):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py in next(self)
   1205         if self.__empty:
   1206             raise StopIteration
-> 1207         if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
   1208             if self.__manipulate:
   1209                 _db = self.__collection.database

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py in _refresh(self)
   1122                                   self.__collection.database.client,
   1123                                   self.__allow_disk_use)
-> 1124             self.__send_message(q)
   1125         elif self.__id:  # Get More
   1126             if self.__limit:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py in __send_message(self, operation)
    997 
    998         try:
--> 999             response = client._run_operation_with_response(
   1000                 operation, self._unpack_response, exhaust=self.__exhaust,
   1001                 address=self.__address)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py in _run_operation_with_response(self, operation, unpack_res, exhaust, address)
   1366                 unpack_res)
   1367 
-> 1368         return self._retryable_read(
   1369             _cmd, operation.read_preference, operation.session,
   1370             address=address,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py in _retryable_read(self, func, read_pref, session, address, retryable, exhaust)
   1469                         # not support retryable reads, raise the last error.
   1470                         raise last_error
-> 1471                     return func(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok)
   1472             except ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
   1473                 if retrying:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py in _cmd(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok)
   1358 
   1359         def _cmd(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok):
-> 1360             return server.run_operation_with_response(
   1361                 sock_info,
   1362                 operation,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py in run_operation_with_response(self, sock_info, operation, set_slave_okay, listeners, exhaust, unpack_res)
    126                 user_fields = None
    127                 legacy_response = True
--> 128             docs = unpack_res(reply, operation.cursor_id,
    129                               operation.codec_options,
    130                               legacy_response=legacy_response,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py in _unpack_response(self, response, cursor_id, codec_options, user_fields, legacy_response)
   1077     def _unpack_response(self, response, cursor_id, codec_options,
   1078                          user_fields=None, legacy_response=False):
-> 1079         return response.unpack_response(cursor_id, codec_options, user_fields,
   1080                                         legacy_response)
   1081 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py in unpack_response(self, cursor_id, codec_options, user_fields, legacy_response)
   1613         # If _OpMsg is in-use, this cannot be a legacy response.
   1614         assert not legacy_response
-> 1615         return bson._decode_all_selective(
   1616             self.payload_document, codec_options, user_fields)
   1617 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bson\__init__.py in _decode_all_selective(data, codec_options, fields)
   1087     """
   1088     if not codec_options.type_registry._decoder_map:
-> 1089         return decode_all(data, codec_options)
   1090 
   1091     if not fields:

InvalidBSON: year -1 is out of range
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of your error.

Comment: @BellyBuster I just did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your data has been stored with a year that python doesn't support (-1). You will need to correct your data before you can proceed in python.

Reference: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-get-overflowerror-decoding-dates-stored-by-another-language-s-driver

Comment: You are awesome!!! It was really helpfull. I removed the date and it worked. Cheers!